# Accepted resource types for Azure Management API, version: 2015-06-01-preview

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I can authenticate and call the Azure Management API through Postman with the URL:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/**Microsoft.Commerce**/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2015-02-01T09%3A00%3A00&reportedEndTime=2015-02-08T09%3A00%3A00&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription-id%7D/providers/**Microsoft.Commerce**/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2015-02-01T09%3A00%3A00&reportedEndTime=2015-02-08T09%3A00%3A00&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false)

But if I try to use any Resource Type other than '**Microsoft.Commerce**', such as 'Microsoft.Compute' then I get an error message of:

"code": "InvalidResourceType",
"message": "The resource type could not be found in the namespace  'Microsoft.Compute' for api version '2015-06-01-preview'."

Is there a restricted list of Resource Types that can be used in the 'preview' version or am I doing something wrong here?

Ps. I retrieved the list of all available resource types using the following API call:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers?$skiptoken={skiptoken}&api-version=**2015-01-01*](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription-id%7D/providers?$skiptoken=%7Bskiptoken%7D&api-version=**2015-01-01*)*

but this won't accept the preview version as it's 'api-version' so it's probably not the right source to get the available types from.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you're doing it the other way around. Essentially each resource provider has an API version and for performing ARM operation on a resource provider and resource type you would need to use that version.

Considering `Microsoft.Compute` resource provider and `virtualMachines` resource type in it, allowed API versions are: 2015-06-15, 2015-05-01-preview.

[image]

You can find this information by using [`Get information about a resource provider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn790534.aspx) API operation.

Comment: thank you Gaurav that's really interesting, I hadn't come across this page. Unfortunately I still get a similar error with the correct resource type as with the Resource Provider: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceNamespace",
    "message": "The resource namespace 'virtualMachines' is invalid."
  }
}

but at least I'll get the terms right now :)

Comment: Ahh I finally get it, the Rest API requires:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/{Resource namespace}/{resource type}

so the example: 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates

works because 'UsageAggregates' is a resource type of the namespace 'Microsoft.Commerce'. I was going wrong because 'UsageAggregates' is not a resource type for say 'Microsoft.Compute'. Thanks again Gaurav, answer accepted!